# Does iptables multiport module provide a performance benefit over multiple separate rules?

Tags: iptables

Does `iptables` multiport module provide a performance benefit over multiple separate rules? In other words, is this:

`iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --sports 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,80 -j ACCEPT`

..more efficient than this:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --sport 1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --sport 2 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --sport 3 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --sport 4 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --sport 5 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --sport 6 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --sport 7 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --sport 8 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --sport 9 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --sport 10 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --sport 11 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --sport 12 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --sport 13 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --sport 14 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --sport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

In the first case, both `tcp` and `multiport` modules are checked for each package, but there is a single rule. In the second case, 15 rules are checked for each package, but for each rule only `tcp` module is processed.

I made a following simple network topology:

```
server1[eth2] <--> [enp0s31f6]server2
```

Both `eth2` in `server1` and `enp0s31f6` in `server2` are 1GigE network adapters and they are connected with 5m Cat5e cable. When I download a 10000 MiB file from `server1` to `server2` without any firewall rules, then throughput was 942Mbps. Then I generated 4369 rules like this:

```
for i in {1..65535}; do if ((i%15 == 0)); then iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --sports $p$i -j ACCEPT; p=; else p=$p$i,; fi; done
```

This means that there were 4369 `multiport` rules with 15 ports in each rule. For example:

```
# iptables -L INPUT 1 -v -n --line-numbers 
1        0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport sports 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15
# iptables -L INPUT 4369 -v -n --line-numbers 
4369     0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport sports 65521,65522,65523,65524,65525,65526,65527,65528,65529,65530,65531,65532,65533,65534,65535
#
```

Now when I executed `wget --report-speed=bits -4 -O /dev/null 10.10.10.1:65535` in `server2`, then to my surprise, throughput was still 942Mbps. As a next step, I flushed the `INPUT` chain and generated 65535 rules like this:

```
for i in {1..65535}; do iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --sport $i -j ACCEPT; done
```

Again, I executed `wget --report-speed=bits -4 -O /dev/null 10.10.10.1:65535` in `server2` and now the throughput dropped to 580Mbps. So am I correct that in extreme cases, the `multiport` approach is more efficient? However, under normal conditions without tens of thousands of rules or tens of Gbps of traffic, there is no practical difference?

Comment: You might still need to accept `NEW` packets if these are internet-facing...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iptables traverses every rule from the table until a match with a terminating target is found, so fewer rules means less CPU usage. Though some rules run faster than others, for example a **multiport** rule for 15 ports might be faster than the equivalent **set** rule (like in Hauke Laging's [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/434565/1174)). So not only the number of rules is important, but their type too.

The source code for [tcp/udp](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/net/netfilter/xt_tcpudp.c?h=v4.15#n23), [multiport](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/net/netfilter/xt_multiport.c?h=v4.15#n29) and [set](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/net/netfilter/xt_set.c?h=v4.15#n228) match extensions offers some rules of thumb, but because [it's hard to predict where things are slow](http://wiki.c2.com/?ProfileBeforeOptimizing), I'd recommend to benchmark the possible iptables rule sets and see which one is faster. For example I run [iperf3](http://software.es.net/iperf/) with a list of just 3 ports, and the **tcp** module was a bit faster than the **multiport** and **set** modules which offered a similar throughput.

If you're still into microbenchmarks, I counted the CPU cycles needed to run the [`ipt_do_table`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/net/ipv4/netfilter/ip_tables.c?h=v4.15#n225) kernel function using this very, very rudimentary [SystemTap](https://sourceware.org/systemtap/) script:

```
global call_cycles = 0

probe kernel.function("ipt_do_table@net/ipv4/netfilter/ip_tables.c").call {
    call_cycles = get_cycles()
}

probe kernel.function("ipt_do_table@net/ipv4/netfilter/ip_tables.c").return {
    delta = get_cycles() - call_cycles
    printf(" <- delta = %d\n", delta)
}
```

These are my results for a packet traversing all the rules on a virtual machine running Linux 4.15:

| Module | Ports | Rules | Run 1 | Run 2 | Run 3 | Run 4 | Run 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| tcp | 4500 | 4500 | 973148 | 1032564 | 856528 | 410894 | 854708 |
| multiport | 4500 | 300 | 89370 | 259250 | 99752 | 225275 | 182256 |
| set | 4500 | 1 | 28463 | 43494 | 28315 | 33589 | 40988 |

Comment: So basically you observed the same behavior as I did. In case of large amount of ports, `multiport` match seems to be more efficient than `tcp` match.

Comment: So set using `bitmap:port range tcp:10000-19999` is a lot faster than multiport? Are the number you repors under "Run" cols best if low or best if high?

Comment: @realtebo the table has the measurements reported by the SystemTap script, i.e. the number of CPU cycles, so lower could mean better (although not all instructions run in the same amount of time).

Comment: @CristianCiupitu: thank. So why do you say "multiport rule for 15 ports might be faster than the equivalent set rule" ? The table show the exact opposite. It's not a polemic. It's just to understand

Comment: @realtebo the benchmark from the table is not for 15 ports, it's for 4500 ports. There could be some speed in the simplicity of __multiport__ compared to the complexity of __set__.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know, how Linux handles Netfilter rules on the opcode level. But the multiport approach could do several checks with a single operation.

As 1Gb/s is not much for a CPU (even a slow one) it is not surprising that you need extreme cases. But both approaches may even at the same throughput generate quite different loads. As this is kernel stuff it is probably not even shown in `/proc/loadavg`. So you would have to run a CPU-intense application on the same system and measure its performance to see the real difference.

But I think that you comparison is kind of unfair because multiport checks once for `-p tcp` whereas multirule does the same check 65536 times. Thus you would to something like this:

```
iptables -N tcp_ports
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -j tcp_ports
for ((i=1;i<65536;i++)); do iptables -A tcp_ports --sport $i ...
```

I just realize that you cannot leave out the TCP check because it is a requirement for `--dport`. But this is one reason why the multirule approach is slower.

I am not sure whether multiport was intended for cases like yours. For huge comparison lists `ipset` was created. So that may be what you are actually looking for.

```
ipset create foo bitmap:port range tcp:10000-19999
ipset add foo tcp:10000-19999
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m set --match-set foo dst
```